White splash screen while navigating routes or at keyboard popup in React Native Expo
import { Redirect, router } from "expo-router";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Image } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { images } from "../constants";
import CustomButton from "../components/CustomButton";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-primary h-full">
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <View className=" w-full justify-center items-center min-h-[85vh] px-4">
          <Image
            source={images.logo}
            className="w-[130px] h-[84px] mt-3"
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
          <Image
            source={images.cards}
            className="max-w-[380px] w-full h-[300px]"
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
          <View className="relative mt-5">
            <Text className="text-3xl text-white font-bold text-center">
              Discover endless posibilites of
              <Text className="text-secondary-200"> Aora!</Text>
            </Text>
            <Image
              source={images.path}
              className="w-[126] h-[15] -bottom-2 -right-4 absolute "
              resizeMode="contain"
            />
          </View>
          <Text className="text-sm font-pregular text-gray-100 mt-7 text-center">
            Where creativity meets innovation: Embark on a journey of limitless
            exploration with Aura
          </Text>
          <CustomButton
            title="Continue With Email"
            handlePress={() => router.push('/signin')}
            containerStyle="w-full"
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#161622" style="light"/> 
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

index.jsx

_layout.jsx:
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, error] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Black": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraLight": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Light": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Medium": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Regular": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "Poppins-SemiBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Thin": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;

    if (fontsLoaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, error]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !error) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen  name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

Whenever i'm navigating to any of the Auth routes or clicking the form field and keyboard popups, a small white slpash can be screen, I want to eliminate that on my React Native Expo App, kindly note, I'm using a dark theme and this white flashes make the app experience look really bad. Above i have attached the _layout.jsx and indx.jsx code, do let me know what changes are required.

Can you make a snack so we can see the problem?

I somehow got rid of the white screen flash while navigating from home-sign in by modifying -{
"expo": {
"name": "tutorial-project",
"slug": "tutorial-project",
"backgroundColor":"#00000",}
but i created an addtional route and went from signin-signup. the white screen flash persists

@Thomasino73 https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/pygdwc/react_navigation_v6_white_flash_when_navigating/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
here you can see the exact video

Are you sure its related to your splashscreen? It might have something to do with your apps background color that gets seen when in-between screens.
In the expo documention for app.json / app.config.js, if you scroll down you will find a value named 'backgroundColor'. Try setting that to your dark theme color and see if that helps.

{
"expo": {
"name": "tutorial-project",
"userInterfaceStyle": "dark",
"backgroundColor":"#000000",
"ios": {
"supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
"package":"com.om.aoraapp",
"backgroundColor":"#000000",
"userInterfaceStyle":"dark"
},
} I have white flash gone while navigating from home-signin, but when i go to signin-up, it appears again. I read expo docs and did all the same.

I would look into NavigationContainer

Documentation


...

export const appTheme: Theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: "black",
  },
};

...

return (
   <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme}>

    ...

   </NavigationContainer>
)


Place NavigationContainer at the top component or at least with your whole navigation state wrapped in. And add a basic theme.
I don't know if this will help but it is worth a try!

If youre using expo native sdk with dark themed app, just do this,
<Stack
      screenOptions={{
        contentStyle: { backgroundColor: "#161626" },
      }}
    >

this will make your entire view contents set to any desired colors you wish. Also fixes the white flash while poping up the keyboard for any input  fields and screen navigation.
